# Google Direction html instruction trouble

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-directions-api

I'm using maneuvers description from the responses of Google server (html-instruction). But there are few problems and I would like to ask:

1) Is it possible to get the names of addresses in the language specified in the query, but not in language of country, where the street is?

example:

- request language: en_US
- country where the route is: Germany

server response:

```
<html_instructions>
Take the 1st <b>right</b> onto <b>Halberstädter Straße</b>
</html_instructions>
```

Is it possible to get something like this:

```
<html_instructions>
Take the 1st <b>right</b> onto <b>Halberstadter Street</b>
</html_instructions>
```

Answers form Geocoding API comes in transcription. Would be perfect to get similar effect here as well.

2) Is it possible to get street names, avenue, bulevards and etc. — not abbreviated but full?

example:

- Indianola Ave: Indianola Aveneu
- Union St: Union Street
- St. Monica blvd: Santa Monica boulevard

Comment: What are you specifying the `region` parameter in your DirectionsRequest as (if anything)?

Comment: @duncan, without any region

Comment: Try adding `region: 'en_US'` in that case